# How to change Facebook language in iPhone sdk?

Tags: iphone, facebook

I am integrating Facebook API for iPhone OS. I want to change the language of the Facebook from English (US) to Spanish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the Facebook Language

Try this

Just go to settings --> General--> International --> Language --> Espanol or Spanish(Select the language you need).

Answer (score 2):

These links of some help to you....

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/beta/opengraph/internationalization/

http://johnklingelhoets.com/facebook-locales-graph-api-array/

First one in particular...